# Django.request is not showing synchronous middleware as docs suggest

Tags: django

I've set up a very simple asynchronous view but it's not working. As per the Django instructions I want to check that it's not my middleware causing the issue. The Django docs say that the django.request logger will disclose which middleware is not working in async. Below is the quote from the official docs. I've set up the django.request logger and it logs an 4xx or 5xx errors (as expected) but that's all. Is this a mistake in the Django docs?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/async/

> You will only get the benefits of a fully-asynchronous request stack if you have no synchronous middleware loaded into your site. If there is a piece of synchronous middleware, then Django must use a thread per request to safely emulate a synchronous environment for it.
>
> Middleware can be built to support both sync and async contexts. Some of Django’s middleware is built like this, but not all. To see what middleware Django has to adapt, you can turn on debug logging for the django.request logger and look for log messages about “Synchronous middleware … adapted”.

settings.py

```
LOGGING = {  
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },

        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/debug.log',
        },


    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'WARNING',
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            #'handlers': ['file','console'],
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

[image]